# Losing performance when coverting Dask do Pandas - compute()

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I'm reading a big text file in python using `Dask` to improve memory performance.

I am converting `Dask` dataframe to `Pandas` using `df.compute()` to perform lots of transformations by Pandas. I see that the memory usage (`guppy3`) after `df.compute()` increases `5x`.

```py
df = dd.read_csv('some_big_file - Copy.csv', sep = '|', names = names)

j = hpy()
print(j.heap())     
##checked only 45mb memory

df = df.compute() 

j = hpy()
print(j.heap())
##Checked almost 230mb memory usage
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `df = df.compute()` brings the dataframe into memory, while before the dataframe was `lazy`, so Python/dask only knew how to access the dataframe, but did not load it into memory.

Comment: Then how to use transformation in the datframe this way?

Comment: The same way you would use pandas, until the final calculation, where you would add `.compute`. See this tutorial: https://github.com/dask/dask-tutorial/blob/main/04_dataframe.ipynb